# Flutter: Cocoapods The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: Flutter.framework

Tags: swift, xcode, dart, flutter, podfile

I am getting this error while running `pod install`

```
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/me/Documents/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.framework)
```

After doing bit of a research it says `use frameworks!` in my `Podfile` is causing the issue. If I comment out `use frameworks!` I get this error. Any idea on what the issue is? I have been stuck here for the past three days.

```
ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Also according to whats written [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10968). Adding the following to `Podfile` also didn't work for me. This is how my `Podfile` looks.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

def parse_KV_file(file,seperator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=seperator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname,:path=>podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  # Flutter Pods
  #use_frameworks!

  pod 'EstimoteSDK'
  pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
  pod 'Alamofire'

  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file("./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig")
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter build or flutter run is executed once first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map{ |p|
    if p[:name]=='FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      pod 'Flutter', :path => p[:path]
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file("../.flutter-plugins")
  plugin_pods.map{ |p|
    pod p[:name], :path => File.expand_path("ios",p[:path])
  }
end

pre_install do |installer|
      # workaround for https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289
      Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Chathanya. Do you figured it out how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete reinstallation of flutter works for me.

Comment: can you please add more details on how to reinstall flutter exactrly?

Comment: Running  ```flutter upgrade``` worked for me.

Answer (score 46):

For me, I deleted the `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` folder and install pods `pod install` again then it worked.

Comment: This should *definitely* be the accepted answer

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: But I don't have `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` folder

Answer (score 13):

Delete `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` folder.

Install pods again then it worked. It will regenerate the deleted folder

`pod install`

Answer (score 10):

In my case I don't have Flutter.framework, so the following solution worked for me

Inside the Podfile `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

Answer (score 5):

This process solve it for me :

1. Delete `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` folder.
2. Delete `ios/PodFile`
3. Delete `ios/PodFile.lock`
4. Go to the project root and re-save the file `pubspec.yaml` (on VSCode, this will automatically runs the following command : `flutter get pub`)
5. Run the project again

Let me know if it works for you too

Answer (score 3):

Delete *ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework* folder.
Install pods again then it worked. It will regenerate the deleted folder
*pod install*

Comment: Correct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your podfile where You see

target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
comment user_frameworks!

target 'Runner' do
comment below line

use_frameworks!
and go to path /ios of the project

run

pod install

Answer (score 2):

Commenting out `use_frameworks!` in the podfile, worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is

- deleted the `ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework` folder
- ran `flutter create -i swift --org com.orgname .`
- I was able to run the app without `pod install` (after this procedure)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the ios/project.pbxproj. I was moved project to another folder and I forgot to replace the FLUTTER_TARGET and FLUTTER_APPLICATION_PATH with the newest one in the ios/project.pbxproj.